# Checking Multiple Conditions for EC2 Volumes

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to check for multiple conditions on an EC2 Volume.

On line 2, it previously read 'if vol.state == 'available':' and this worked. I now need to exclude any volumes with the 'Name' tag that has a value that starts with 'CloudEndure'. I added code so line 2 now reads 'if vol.state == 'available' and not [{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values':['CloudEndure*']}]:' and it fails with with a syntax error.

```
    for vol in ec2.volumes.all():
        if vol.state == 'available' and not [{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values':['CloudEndure*']}]:
            vid=vol.id
            v=ec2.Volume(vol.id)
            response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('volID').eq(vid),
            )
            if response['Count'] == 0: #volume not being tracked in table
                try:
                    response = table.put_item(
                        Item={
                            'volID': vid,
                            'ebsDaysToExpire': 7,
                            'snapshotStatus': 'incomplete',
                            'snapshotDate': 'incomplete',
                            'lifecycleStatus': 'start_7',
                            'snapshotID': 'incomplete',
                            'snapshotDaysToExpire': '30'
                        },
                        ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(volID)'
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own with the help of a co-worker, had to get familiar with regular expressions and I found that the ^ represents 'not'. I also needed to add 'import re' near the top of the function to import regualr expressions. The new code is below. This exclude volumes where the name starts with 'CloudEndure' which is what I was after.

```
    for vol in ec2.volumes.all():
        cloudendure=False
        for tag in vol.tags:
            if tag['Key'] == 'Name' and re.search("^CloudEndure.*",tag['Value']):
               cloudendure=True
               #print(tag)
        if vol.state == 'available' and cloudendure==False:
            vid=vol.id
            v=ec2.Volume(vol.id)
            response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('volID').eq(vid),
            )
            if response['Count'] == 0: #volume not being tracked in table
                try:
                    response = table.put_item(
                        Item={
                            'volID': vid,
                            'ebsDaysToExpire': 7,
                            'snapshotStatus': 'incomplete',
                            'snapshotDate': 'incomplete',
                            'lifecycleStatus': 'start_7',
                            'snapshotID': 'incomplete',
                            'snapshotDaysToExpire': '30'
                        },
                        ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(volID)'
                        )
```